# Using split on multiple strings with different delimiters

Tags: python, regex, dictionary, split

Say I have to split multiple strings within a for loop, which is separated with different delimiters. For example, here in the following example, I have `.` and `-` as delimiters.

I wanna split the strings and use the first part of the string. 
The example strings look like this,

```
ASD-2.T-bR.r1-v1_0
VXD.T-bR.r1-v1_0
VSR.T_bR_r1v1.0
SAP-LT_bR_r1v1.0
```

From the strings I need the string before the first `.` and `-` delimiters.
I tried using,

```
for sam, keys in samp_dic.items():
        print(lab_key.split('.-',1)[0])
```

All the strings are values in a dictionary. The expected output is,

```
ASD
VXD
VSR
SAP
```

**PS: The marked question (Split string with multiple delimiters in Python [duplicate] ) is for strings, my question is based on strings within dictionary**

Comment: I have edited my question now, with expected output

Comment: `print([re.split(r"\.|-", s, 1)[0] for s in data.splitlines()])`

Comment: You can use regex with `(?<=\n|^)([^-.]+)` (assuming multiple lines) or `(?<=^)([^-.]+)` only work with first line

Comment: Actually, `re.split` will not work on a dictionary

Comment: @OlvinRoght, The `regular expression` solution throws error as the data is a dictionary

Comment: @user1017373 replace `data.splitlines()` with `data.values()` or `data,keys()`.

Comment: @OlvinRoght, I tried both, Firstly,  `[re.split(r"\.|-", s, 1)[0] for s,lab in samp_dic.keys().splitlines()]` then, it threw the same error, `AttributeError: 'dict_keys' object has no attribute 'splitlines'`. Secondly, if you completely replace like this: `[re.split(r"\.|-", s, 1)[0] for s,lab in samp_dic.keys()]`. Then it throws: `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

Comment: @user1017373 you don't understand what are you doing. Correct way is `print([re.split(r"\.|-", s, 1)[0] for s in data.values()])`.